# No prompt for client-side certificate when deploying nginx server on k8s with load balancer service

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, client-certificates, kubernetes-service

My web server backend enforces a client-side certificate. This worked great until I moved my deployment to a Kubernetes cluster. My guess is that the forwarding rules are not passing on the certificate request from the server to the browser.

I'm using [uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker container](https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker).

My Nginx configuration is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 8000 ssl;
    location / {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params; uwsgi_param SSL_CLIENT_S_DN $ssl_client_s_dn;

        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 300;

        ssl_certificate     /app/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /app/key.pem;
        ssl_password_file   /app/password.pass;

        ssl_client_certificate  /app/client-ca.crt;
        ssl_verify_client off;
        ssl_verify_depth 2;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /app/static;
    }
}
```

When deploying this server on a local container, I'm getting `SSL_CLIENT_S_DN` in `flask.request.environ`, as expected.

On my Kubernetes cluster, the variable is just empty and no certificate demand is popped on the browser.

My service and deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-server
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-server
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: XX.XX.XXX.XXX
  ports:

  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-server
  labels:
    app: my-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-server
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      hostname: my-server
      containers:

      - name: my-server
        image: asia.gcr.io/my-project/my-server:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: LISTEN_PORT
          value: "8000 ssl"
```

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/auth/client-certs

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes supports [multiple means of authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/) which are: [X509](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#x509-client-certs), [Static Token File](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#static-token-file), [Bootstrap Tokens](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#bootstrap-tokens), [Static Password File](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#static-password-file), [Service Account Tokens](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens) and [OpenID Connect Tokens](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#openid-connect-tokens).

[Here](https://brancz.com/2017/10/16/kubernetes-auth-x509-client-certificates/) is a link to a Blog post by [Frederic Branczyk](https://github.com/brancz) who explains how to setup X509 client certificates.

He creates a `ClusterRole` with read-only permission for all pods and namespaces:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: read-only-user
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

Then granting a user these permissions in `ClusterRoleBinding`

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-only-users
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: read-only-user
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: brancz
```

> The above `ClusterRoleBinding` gives the user named “brancz” the roles specified in the `ClusterRole` called “read-only-user”

You can also have a look at the automation script that he uses to generate the client certificates, signs them with cluster's CA and generates a `kubeconfig`.

I hope this helps You.

Comment: doesn't seem like any Kubernetes-level solution would allow me to pass the certificate DN to my application like I wanted (`uwsgi_param SSL_CLIENT_S_DN $ssl_client_s_dn`)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had the same problem, turned out it was simply an error in my ca.crt 
Bad copy paste I guess, check to make sure your clients cert's signer is located in the ca.crt chain, if its not nginx will fail silently.